# Common alternative to $C$ for line integrals?

Tags: soft-question, line-integrals

I am aware that this is a soft-question (hence the tag) but feel this question still is warranted in this community.

I'm writing a proof for the circumference of a circle using a line integral. Naturally I'm using $C(r)$ to represent circumference. The problem is that basically every text I've ever seen on line integrals uses the subscript $C$ to represent the curve along which we are integrating. Naturally, I don't want something that looks like this:

$$C(r)=\oint_Cds$$

Is there any common alternative subscript to replace $C$ such that this doesn't confuse a reader? I realise this may seem trivial but it's for a formal textbook and I'd like to use as conventional of notation as possible.

Comment: IME the circle is already this alternative unless there are multiple paths under discussion simultaneously (e.g. in decomposition of a contour integral into components) in which case you can use subscripts $C_1,C_2$ etc. But names don't really matter much, use the name you like.

Comment: You can call it whatever - I sometimes see circles (and curves, for that matter) called $\Gamma$ in complex variables texts.

Comment: Sometimes one see $\Gamma$ as the name of a curve.

Comment: Appreciate the responses, I'll be taking complex this fall.

Is $\Gamma$ or $\gamma$ more common?

Comment: I think $\gamma$ is more common.  Another one you will see in complex analysis is $\oint_{|z|=r}$ or similar.